# Can MvvmCross use 3rd party Views that are defined inside of external assemblies (i.e. platform-specific Views it has no control over)?

Tags: authentication, xamarin, mvvmcross, azure-mobile-services

**Why?**

I am trying to create an Mvx Authentication Plugin that reuses existing 3rd party code AND its platform-specific UIs as much as possible.  There are some SO posts on how to reference Mvx-specific View/ViewModel's in another assembly, but I would like to know if there is any way for Mvx to support navigating to and/or displaying a View/ViewModel that it did not create/control?

I assume I have to somehow tell Mvx about the "extra external login View" to even have a chance of it working, but I do not know if it is possible to do it when I don’t control the platform-specific View/ViewModel that is provided in an external DLL.

**Current Approach That Is Not Working**

Let's call my Mvx AuthN Plugin:

```
Acme.MvvmCross.Plugins.Authentication
```

This plugin's core PCL just contains some PCL-friendly enums, simple POCO's, and the `IAuthenticationProvider` that the associated platform-specific plugin projects will implement.

Over time, various 3rd party "Authentication Gateways" may be supported as valid platform-specific implementations of the `IAuthenticationProvider` interface.

The first 3rd party that the Mvx plugin will support is, "Windows Azure Mobile Services (AMS)", on Windows Phone 7.5/8 & Win8.  AMS already provides a C# PCL to provide authentication on WP7/8 & Win 8: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services and I will worry about adding the Xamarin-provided iOS/Droid implementations of these later: https://github.com/xamarin/azure-mobile-services.

The AMS approach is to have a core PCL: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile`
and they combine that core with platform-specific extensions and UI View(s) as needed.

**Example:**

Inside of my plugin's WP75-specific library project (`Acme.MvvmCross.Plugins.Authentication.WindowsPhone`), this is what the AMS NuGet references:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.WP75
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.UI.WP75
```

Note that my plugin's core PCL (`Acme.MvvmCross.Plugins.Authentication`) does NOT reference ANY of these AMS DLLs.

I am able to reference and use the above Mvx Plugin in my App's PCL core and the App's client-specific projects, BUT I am unable to get the platform-specific "Login View" (provided by the AMS SDK) to display on the WP7/8 clients, they just lock-up when I call AMS's LoginAsync method.

**Example:**

If you do not use Mvx, the AMS samples show how a client-specific project can just call it's shared "[`LoginAsync`](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/IMobileServiceClient.cs#L91)" method and by doing that, the client-specific extensions and UI's that they provide magically kick-in to display the Authentication Provider's screen to let the user login (Twitter's login inside of a web view on the phone for example).

When I call AMS's `LoginAsync` from my Mvx App's `LoginViewModel` (via an Mvx Service in the same App that is using my Mvx plugin), the custom login UI provided by AMS does not display, the client just locks-up.

Is there any way to reuse the existing/ongoing Azure/Xamarin AMS work via the Mvx plugin model or is that not going to happen?

*Note: The AMS SDK source is available from both Microsoft and Xamarin, but I will likely avoid this approach if I have to maintain custom-MVX-specific forks of both of those repos to make this all work as desired.*

Comment: Is this similar to using the built-in views/tasks to capture a photo? In which case does the source to the picture chooser plugin help? Stuart (on mobile)

Comment: I'm not sure. If ultimately my Mvx service is calling out to the underlying "LoginAsync" (provided my plugin wrapping Azure DLL) that auto-magically tries to load/navigate to this PhoneApplicationPage https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WindowsPhone8.UI/Authentication/AuthenticationBroker.cs#L92 , should it "just work" or do I need to help Mvx understand how to deal with this native WP8 page in order to show it after the user licks an auth provider on the MvxPhonePage that is showing the list of login options?

Comment: Using the MvxPictureChooser & EMail plugins as a guide to see how they used "MvxWindowsPhoneTask" was a step in the right direction.  I was able to get the AMS client to finally display the login screen for twitter as expected! I had to use the Action param of "DoWithInvalidOperationProtection" though so I am currently losing my return type & have no error checking anymore. There are some things I did while using your plugins as a guide that don't seem right so I am going to clean it up and then ask if I am using Mvx correctly before I/We can post an updated answer here. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to [this dialog messages solution](http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/11/returning-results-from-view-models-in-mvvmcross/). you basically use the messenger and listen for an Authenticate message in the views for each platform to show your login UI and fire a message back when it's done.

I'm using the old Azure ACS controls in a similar way (firing an message to show them and binding to events on the usercontrol for the result)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will look at that. If you look at my comment to Stuart under the original question, do you know for sure that using that simple direct call to "LoginAsync" in the AMS DLL will for sure NOT display the auth provider's login screen without using this messenger-based approach? Meaning, is it possible I could get it to work as desired (call LoginAsync and let it's built-in login view display itself) or based on your understanding is it NOT going to be possible in Mvx without this workaround?

Comment: EShy - I think the answer to this is going to be in the realm of what Stuart suggested above because I was able to use that plugin approach and just call LoginAsync without having to pass messages around.  I want to see what the final answer ends up looking like before I accept/enter an answer here.  Thanks!